# Formik field.value stale in onClick handler

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am trying to build a custom form field in Formik for table sorting. I have a number of `<th>` elements whose `onClick` handlers feed up into a single callback (`onSort`), this is then fed into a `Field` like so to track the current value of the sorting key:

```
<Formik
  initialValues={{
    sort: 'date',
  }}
>
  <Form validate={...}>
    <Field name="sort">
      {({ field, form }) => <>
        <input {...field} />
        <Table onSort={key => {
          console.log(field.value); // This is always the initial value!
          key = maybeInvertKey(key, field.value);
          form.setFieldValue(field.name, key);
         }} />
      </>
    </Field>
  </Form>
</Formik>
```

Interestingly the `validate` function is called with the correct value. The input also shows the correct value. I just can't access that value the next time my `onClick` handler fires. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this was a mistake due to memoization, which I will share now for the next person who runs into a similar issue.

I discovered that the render function to `Field` was correctly emitting the correct `field` object. However this would not appear in `onSort`. That continued to use an old object.

The problem was not in the form at all, but inside the `Table` there was a `useMemo` on the table headers, that did not depend on the `onSort` callback. Hence when the `onSort` callback was being recalculated, the headers were not not being recalculated, and I was calling an old version of the callback, which included old data in its closure.

The lesson here is to watch out for callbacks being included in `useMemo`, they might be calling an old version of your closure.

Comment: Thanks, I had the exact issue, you pointed me the right direction!